# React: Error in build Failed to minify the code from this file - ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/node.js:282

Tags: reactjs, build, dependencies, react-scripts

Getting error while creating build

```
Failed to minify the code from this file: 

./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/node.js:282
```

The asn1 package comes with **azure-storage**

Version details

> "react": "^16.13.1"
> "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
> "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",

Is there anyway the issue can get solved without updating version of react/react-sripts?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking from the path that you've provided in the question, I'm concerned about the fact that the module folder name is `asn1.js` whilst after installing ASN1js module from NPM, the directory name that is being created is called `asn1js`. Also, upon installing `azure-storage`, we're getting a module folder called `asn1`, but definitely not `asn1.js`.
Can you check if the naming of the folder is correct? This could be the cause of minifying failure, since the script for minifying can't find the module in that folder.

Comment: I rechecked and the file name and dependency name is correct, I've also updated the question wirh an screenshot of the directory please check!

Comment: Could you post your whole `package.json` file dependency list if it's not a problem? From the screenshot I see multiple `asn1` modules. After installing `azure-storage` scripts, only one of them got generated, which is the `asn1` one.

Comment: I am having the same problem -- but Azure is not a component here with asn1.js, same line of code, but Azure is not involved in my project at all.

Answer (score 0):

Open library file and change variable type from `let` to `var` one by one as you build